# mysql query name from list id

Tags: php, mysql, sql, group-by

i have a little problem here...
let me explain..

lets say i have a table like this...

Barang

```
╔══════════╦════════════╦════════════╗
║ IDBARANG ║    NAMA    ║ IDKATEGORI ║
╠══════════╬════════════╬════════════╣
║        1 ║ Ban Becak  ║ 1,3        ║
║        2 ║ Velg Becak ║ 2,4        ║
╚══════════╩════════════╩════════════╝
```

Kategori

```
╔════════════╦══════════════╗
║ IDKATEGORI ║ NAMAKATEGORI ║
╠════════════╬══════════════╣
║          1 ║ Ban Dalam    ║
║          2 ║ Velg Canggih ║
║          3 ║ Ban Keren    ║
║          4 ║ Velg Monster ║
╚════════════╩══════════════╝
```

And my question is.. how to fetch so the result become like this

```
╔══════════╦════════════╦═══════════════════════════╗
║ IDBARANG ║    NAMA    ║        IDKATEGORI         ║
╠══════════╬════════════╬═══════════════════════════╣
║        1 ║ Ban Becak  ║ Ban Keren,Ban Dalam       ║
║        2 ║ Velg Becak ║ Velg Monster,Velg Canggih ║
╚══════════╩════════════╩═══════════════════════════╝
```

I try to use FIND_IN_SET but gets nothing...

thanks before for your help...

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you have missed something else when you use `FIND_IN_SET()`

```
SELECT  a.idBarang,
        a.nama,
        GROUP_CONCAT(b.namaKategori) idKategori
FROM    barang a
        INNER JOIN Kategori b
            ON FIND_IN_SET(b.idKategori, a.idKategori)
GROUP   BY a.idBarang, a.nama
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c17d7/1)

OUTPUT

```
╔══════════╦════════════╦═══════════════════════════╗
║ IDBARANG ║    NAMA    ║        IDKATEGORI         ║
╠══════════╬════════════╬═══════════════════════════╣
║        1 ║ Ban Becak  ║ Ban Keren,Ban Dalam       ║
║        2 ║ Velg Becak ║ Velg Monster,Velg Canggih ║
╚══════════╩════════════╩═══════════════════════════╝
```

The ideal thing to do for now is to normalized the table. It is a bad practice to store values in comma separated value in a single column. If this is a `Many-to-Many` relationship, transform the current design into three-table database.

**Barang**

- idBarang (PK)
- Name

**Kategori**

- idkategori (PK)
- namaKategori

**Barang_Kategori**

- idBarang (FK)
- idkategori (FK)

---

Sample Records

**Barang**

```
╔══════════╦════════════╗
║ IDBARANG ║    NAMA    ║
╠══════════╬════════════╣
║        1 ║ Ban Becak  ║
║        2 ║ Velg Becak ║
╚══════════╩════════════╝
```

**Kategori**

```
╔════════════╦══════════════╗
║ IDKATEGORI ║ NAMAKATEGORI ║
╠════════════╬══════════════╣
║          1 ║ Ban Dalam    ║
║          2 ║ Velg Canggih ║
║          3 ║ Ban Keren    ║
║          4 ║ Velg Monster ║
╚════════════╩══════════════╝
```

**Barang_Kategori**

```
╔══════════╦════════════╗
║ IDBARANG ║ IDKATEGORI ║
╠══════════╬════════════╣
║        1 ║          1 ║
║        1 ║          3 ║
║        2 ║          2 ║
║        2 ║          4 ║
╚══════════╩════════════╝
```

NEW QUERY

```
SELECT  a.idBarang,
        a.nama,
        GROUP_CONCAT(c.namaKategori) KategoryLista
FROM    barang a
        INNER JOIN Barang_Kategori b
            ON a.idBarang = b.idBarang
        INNER JOIN Kategori c
            ON b.idKategori = c.idKategori
GROUP   BY a.idBarang, a.nama
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a8fcd/3)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `JOIN` in your query. Here's tutorial on the subject:

http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/

Answer (score -1):

I do not know if this query would work, just double check it if there's a mistake:

```
SELECT Barang . idBarang , Barang . Nama , Kategori . namaKategori AS `idKategori`
FROM Barang
INNER JOIN Kategori ON Barang . idKategori = Kategori . idKategori
ORDER BY Barang . idBarang
```

But the output of the query above will be the table below if the numbers on `Barang . idKategori` are separated like the very bottom table in code, anyway you can still try the code above:

```
idBarang | Nama | idKategori
-----------------------------------
1. | Ban Becak | Ban Dalam
1. | Ban Becak | Ban Keren
2. | Velg Becak| Velg Canggih
2. | Velg Becak| Velg Monster
```

If the query didn't work. Just try to separate the numbers on `Barang . idKategori` like below, only if you would like to do so! Surely it would work like the table above.

```
Barang
---------------
idBarang | Nama | idKategori
-------------------------------
1 | Ban Becak | 1
1 | Ban Becak | 3
2 | Velg Becak | 2
2 | Velg Becak | 4
```